# difference between jQuery(document).on("click") & document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I observed a scenario where `jQuery(document).on("click", "#sign-out", function(e)` and `document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function(e)` are behaving differently.

I am trying to bind a click event to sign-out page link, which is visible on every page of the application once user is logged in.

When i am adding an event listener using `document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function(e)` **its not getting called when i visit the inner pages of the application** but when i am using `jQuery(document).on("click", "#sign-out", function(e)` the function is triggered on inner pages too.

my event listener code is as below

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#sign-out", function(e) {

      //document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     createStats().complete(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/logout',
          method: 'POST',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
          complete: function() {
            window.location.replace('/users/sign_in');
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

`createStats` returns an ajax call.

is this the expected behaviour or is there something that i am doing incorrectly.

Any help on this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour because the two excerpts are not equivalent:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#sign-out", function(e)
```

is not the same as

```
document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener('click', function(e)
```

the equivalent jQuery to the vanilla version is:

```
jQuery("#sign-out").on("click", function(e)
```

Notice the event handler is registered on the element with and id of `sign-out`, whereas your jQuery example is registered against the document.

When clicking anywhere in the page jQuery will check whether the click event could have targeted an element with and id of `sign-out`. Doing it this way means that if the `#sign-out` doesn't exists in the DOM when the event handler is registered, it will still get triggered later when you click on said element.

With the vanilla (and vanilla equivalent jQuery) the element is not found and no event handler is registered if you attempt to register the handler before the element exists in the DOM.

Comment: thanks for your reply. one thing that still is not clear is why would the event registered via vanilla js fire the first time and not the second time?

Comment: Without knowing what's happening between the clicks, I'd guess that the DOM has changed and the element has been removed/replaced and the handler has not been rebound.

Comment: the element is definitely in the DOM, so are you suggesting that if the element is present in the DOM then document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener should also work?

Comment: If the element exists in the DOM then `document.getElementById('sign-out').addEventListener` will work until it is removed, perhaps replaced.

Comment: the strange thing is the element exists in the DOM is not replaced, but still the event does not fire, I am using rails turbolinks, may be i need to catch the event differently.